# Forwarding from Servlet to JSP

Tags: model-view-controller, jsp, el

I am trying to implement the MVC2 model.
I have a Servlet that fetches data from a session bean and forwards the entity from the servlet to a jsp:

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet{

@EJB UserFacade userFacade;  

//Fetch the user from the session bean  
Users currUser=userFacade.find(userName);  
...
request.setAttribute("user", currUser);  
getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request, response);  
}
```

in index.jsp: I get the user from the request, and I can print its name if I use scriptlets tags, but when I use EL nothing is printed:

```
<@page import="Entities.Users">  
 <"Users currUser = (Users)request.getAttribute("user");">  
 <= currUser.getName() > -OK!  
 ${currUser.name}-Nothing is printed!
```

How should I include/forward the session-bean into the JSP in order to be able to use EL (and avoid using scriptlets)?
Is this the preferred way to implement the Model View controller?

Comment: The title and the question is a little confusing. You are not forwarding from the session bean, but from the Servlet. If your interpretation of the English verb "forwarding" is "storing into a scope" then this too is not applicable. You are storing the result of a call to session bean into the scope. The entire session bean and ejb-3.1 tag seem unnecessary for this question.

Answer (score 2):

EL uses request attributes. You don't have `currUser` as request attributes. If you try  `${user.name}` it will work.

I'm not sure what you mean by "session bean". EJBs are session beans, but you didn't show anything about it in the view. But anyway - EJBs should not be accessible in the view.

In short - you are using the correct approach - just use EL with the attributes that you've set.